# Unity OnTriggerEnter is not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a flying Dagger with a trigger surrounding it so when it hits an enemy or wall it returns. However sometimes the Dagger just flies straight through. I suspect that happens because its velocity is too high(200), is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is, almost for sure, caused by the high velocity, and in fact this problem is known as "bullet through paper". There are some tricks to address this issue.

1. As a start, if you are using a Rigidbody, you can go for the [dynamic collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html): this reduces the performances, but it helps a lot for this problem.
2. You can use Raycasting rather than Collisions, in order to check for the bullet impact.
3. A trivial advice: in case of the walls, you could just extend the collider in the direction for which the scene does not take place anymore: this way, you would have "wider" walls, but outside of the game field.

Comment: I tried setting it to continous and continous dynamic collision detection but it still goes right through :/
Can i do it with overlapsphere or will that be the same problem? Raycasts would be really hard to integrate in this case.